# Is there a way to have a piece of VBA code interupt cell calculation?

Tags: vba, excel

In an excel project, I have several thousand cells that will display a message box if some user entered data is invalid. Thing is, right now, every time you calculate, you have to close down several hundred message boxes before you can fix the error. **Is there a way to have the VBA function that displays the message box also stop the calculation of any other cells?**

EDIT: I'm not really looking for some alternate solution to the several hundred message box problem. If I need to, it isn't too hard to fix that. However, I am interested in knowing if there is any way to have a VBA function stop cell calculation, partially because I can see some other uses for it.

Comment: `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

Comment: Why not just do `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual ` at the start of your macro, then go through the range looking for whatever would trigger the message box, and then reset calculation after?  Perhaps you can add that *right before* your `msgbox`, but your other data may have already calculated.  What code do you have so far?

Comment: Better design would be to have several thousand cells that display ***one*** message box if ***any number*** of them are invalid.

Comment: The spreadsheet is large enough that I already set the xl calculation to manual, so I don't have to wait two minutes every time I change a cell. What I need is a single cell's calculation to interrupt the cell calculation so that the cells that would be calculated after aren't calculated unless I restart calculation. I know it's possible for a user to interrupt calculation using the esc key, but can a VBA function do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why raise MessageBoxes at all?  Tempted to create your own error messages? 
Actually returning strings is bad says Chip Pearson [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ReturningErrors.aspx).  Use CVErr instead for fast fail.

Or follow the advice of [ComIntern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4088852/comintern) by which I think he means write a function that accepts a large block of cells, loop through the cells yourself in code and then break out of loop on first error.

Comment: In the end this is exactly what I did. At the same time, though it does solve my specific issue, it doesn't answer the question itself. Is it possible to have VBA code interrupt cell calculation?

Comment: I have changed my answer.